# How do I properly set my constraints for an adaptive layout?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am extremely bad at creating layouts for multiple screen orientations. All along I've been using suggested constraints on Auto-Layout but sometimes they don't work as desired. I've been trying to learn how set up my layouts properly by reading and watching tutorials, but I still cannot understand how exactly constraints work!

What I am trying to do is to make the button widths equally like so in iPhone 7:

[image]

But on other devices such as iPhone 4S, the second button width shrinks, which is not what I wanted:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how constraints work in **layman terms**? I do not understand things like:

- Leading/Trailing Space
- Constrain to margins
- Equal Widths and Heights
- Top, Bottom, Baseline etc. (What do they even mean?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to make two equal-width buttons:

1. Create two buttons
2. Add a vertical position constraint to each button.  For example, you could position them in the center of the parent view using the "Align->Vertically in Container" function (in the lower-lefthand corner of the interface builder window)
3. Select both buttons.  Add an equal width constraint between them using "Add New Constraints->Equal Widths"
4. Constrain the left edge of the left button to the leading edge of the parent view
5. Constrain the right edge of the left button to the left edge of the right button.  Add space between the buttons using the "Constant" property of the constraint you created.
6. Constrain the right edge of the right button to the right edge of the parent view

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! Now it looks equal across multiple devices. I think I am able to understand how some constrains work a little now, but can you explain what does the center vertically in container constraint do? Wouldn't it move the button to the middle?

Comment: Yes -- that was just an example.  You can add a different vertical constraint.  If that works, can you accept the answer? Thanks! :-D